# Accidently write flutter clean

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, flutter-packages

In between project, I ran the command "flutter clean", now lots of error are showing. When I'm trying to run "flutter pub get" it's no more working, I'm getting following errors["flutter pub get" and "flutter cache repair" are not working, I've also cleared the cache, I've now no idea how to fix it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIZ7z.png)["Flutter cache repair" not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH9gA.png)

Tried "flutter pub get" and "flutter pub cache repair" none of them are working. Want to get rid of all the errors.

Comment: Can you run `flutter doctor`?

Comment: you cannot run pub get because of version solving issue.... try downgrading firebase messaging  package or upgrading all firebase packages.